# CNAME records query

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

I have a control panel with Enta which lets me mess with my DNS settings. So I have added a CNAME record to point to an IP address.

Assume my website is called:

```
www.example.com
```

I have added a CNAME like this:

```
subdomain.example.com -> This works fine.
```

But now I wish to add another CNAME for the following to point to the same IP:

```
www.subdomain.example.com
```

This is proving to be not possible as it says **I can't add "." in the name when I try to create the record**.

Any help?

Comment: Subdomains with dots in your zone file are perfectly legal. That seems an artificial limitation in your control panel, which is why many professionals avoid them like the plague and edit configuration files directly.

Comment: I assume that Enta is your ISP. You need to file a complaint and/or support ticket for this, then.

Comment: Please delete this question if you "No longer need help with this".

Comment: @user223346 I've rolled back your edit to preserve the question.  If you no longer want it then delete it.  If you no longer need help it would be best to add an answer explaining how you resolved your issue for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add

```
www.subdomain IN CNAME www.example.com.
```

If your control panel is not allowing "." in the record, maybe there are a few ways to deal with this...

1. by adding a catchall record, this would effectively make any subdomain name go to "www"

> * IN CNAME www.example.com.

2. Drop shell on the box and manually add the record to zone file.  ff your zone files are in an obscure place, you can see where by grepping thru `lsof`. After the change, make a completely different change thru the control panel (such as adding TXT record), so as to let bind reload via mgmt interface (the control panel will make changes on its own such as incrementing zone file serial number.)  Be ready revert changes if it breaks.
3. Stop using control panel GUI.  All you really need is ssh and vim. Linux does not need a GUI and/or control panel to serve up DNS, or whatever.